# Grub-Customizer uninstallable on Ubuntu 23.04?

Tags: dual-boot, apt, grub2, ppa

I'm trying to install Grub-Customizer on my system, however I keep getting the following output when adding the PPA:

```
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-lunar.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer-lunar.list
Adding key to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/danielrichter2007-ubuntu-grub-customizer.gpg with fingerprint 59DAD276B942642B1BBD0EACA8AA1FAA3F055C03
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Get:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-updates InRelease [90.7 kB]    
Ign:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu lunar InRelease
Hit:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-backports InRelease            
Hit:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lunar-security InRelease             
Err:6 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu lunar Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Hit:7 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu lunar Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Ultimately, when I then do `sudo apt-get install grub-customizer` it fails.

I'd read somewhere that it had originally been removed from Ubuntu 22.04 due to a logic error but this had been fixed?

Is there any way I can get it installed onto my system?

Thanks!

Comment: If you checked https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer you'll have noted *lunar* or 23.04 isn't supported (*yet anyway*).

Comment: It is up to the person or group that produces this app to upgrade and make it work with any new version of the Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Manually modifying some grub settings is not difficult. You do have to edit a file or two. Customizer replaces all of the grub scripts with its own proxy versions, so has to be updated with every grub change.

Comment: The answer is here: https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Instalando-Grub-Customizer-no-Ubuntu-2204. `sudo apt install gdebi; wget https://launchpadlibrarian.net/570407966/grub-customizer_5.1.0-3build1_amd64.deb; sudo gdebi grub-customizer*`